# I have a combi boiler and since yesterday the radiators are getting really hot even when thermostat is turned right down

Tags: radiator

Radiators getting hot even when thermostat is turned right down. Its a Worcester combined boiler

Comment: What model is it?

Comment: As I understand it, the room-thermostat just determines when the boiler comes on and for how long, it doesn't affect radiator temperature. Radiator temperature is mainly controlled by the boiler temperature setting.

Comment: A little more information would be helpful. did this just start happening? is the boiler cycling on and off?

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if a [zone valve is stuck open](http://masterplumber.net/taco_zone.htm).
2. Check if there's another thermostat (e.g. behind furniture) calling for heat.
3. If the thermostat is battery operated (e.g. on a timer), check that the battery is OK.